# Debugging Automator Actions in Xcode 4

Tags: cocoa, xcode4, automator

I created some Automator Actions (Cocoa, not AppleScript) in Xcode 3, and that allowed me to debug the actions by doing a Build and Debug from the Build menu, which would open Automator with that action added and I could debug as normal as documented at the below link (in the Testing, Debugging, and Installing the Action section):

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/AutomatorConcepts/Articles/DevelopAction.html

In Xcode 4 I cannot find any way to do this, the Run option in the Product menu is greyed out and the Run button in the toolbar just builds the action.

Is there a way of doing this in Xcode 4, or is this no loner possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue for Xcode4, here is the work-around to modify the scheme to make it work:

http://www.macosxautomation.com/automator/xcodefix/index.html

Comment: Thanks that was very useful, although I was confused at first as the instructions refer to the "Run Automator.app" step in the scheme. At least for me, the name of the step when first editing the scheme is  just "Run" and only becomes "Run Automator.app" when the Automator app is selected as the executable for that step.